# Vue - make helper for root component and all child component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

Please is there a way to create a helper function on a root component in vue and also make the function accessible in all child components?

Comment: You can use `mixin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create helper functions and use it as a plugin. In case of you are using nuxt.js, you can create helpers.js in plugins and register it in nuxt.config.js file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import helpers from './helpers'

const plugin = {
  install () {
    Vue.prototype.$helpers = helpers
  }
}

Vue.use(plugin)
```

In helpers.js, you can define all helper functions.

```
export default { 
  cloneObj(val) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(val));
  }
};
```

Then you can use it in any child components like this:

```
this.$helpers.cloneObj()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it in a separate file because it's frustrating to pass it as a prop from one component to another and that's the main idea of why state management like `Vuex` is a better solution because it provides a centralized state manage which you can access from any component